# How to use collation for pattern matching in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, qnx

For example if in the sqlite database have entries Resume, Résumé ,RESUME  and if we enter

> select Name from NAME_TABLE where Name like 'Re%%'

It should return all
But like does not support collation , any-other way to do pattern matching using collation ?

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, LIKE always uses the NOCASE or BINARY collations.

You could redefine LIKE by install a user-defined [like() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#like), but you could just as well use your own function with a different name.